Can I use Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) to query data (such as groups) in Microsoft Entra Admin Center?
There is UI to query/filter users/groups. I'm wondering if there is kusto connection to do that. thx.


Note that, there isn't a direct Kusto query connection to Microsoft Entra Admin Center, Alternatively, you can retrieve data using the Microsoft Graph API and then ingest it into Azure Data Explorer for analysis.

As mentioned in this blog by AdamMarczakIO, it's not possible to query/filter Microsoft Entra groups directly in KQL as they are not Azure resources.
Alternatively, you can make use of below Microsoft Graph API calls to query/filter users or groups in Graph Explorer.
Users:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=startswith(displayName,'sri')&$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName


Groups:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'demo')&$select=id,displayName


References:
List users - Microsoft Graph v1.0
List groups - Microsoft Graph v1.0

thanks. I have been using this approach!
